# How can I change my gmail address

Tags: email, gmail

I Set up a silly gmail address when I was younger and now I'd like to have a better email address now that I'm ready for the world of college but I don't want to loose all my old email and I don't want to have to check two email accounts.

Can I just change my email address or something?

Comment: Migration with http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/how-can-i-change-my-gmail-address wouldn't add any new keywords

Comment: @random If you are going to close my useful question, please at least migrate the question to webapps.  Its not the same as the question you linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite, but there is quite a simple solution.  You can set up a gmail forward on your old email address.

The first thing to do is set up a new gmail (or other) email address.  Once you have done this log into your old gmail and go to the settings.

Then click on Forwarding and Pop Tab

[image]

Next select  Add a Forwarding Address

[image]

Enter your new email address into the box.

[image]

Gmail will send you an email to your new email address asking if it is ok to forward all mail, click on the link provided.

The last thing is to delete the origional copy as its now being sent on to your new email.  Select from the list beside your verified email address

[image]

After that you never need to check your old gmail again as you will receive all the email in your new account, and over time your friends will learn your new email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple different gmail accounts (I wonder if there is a limit). You don't need to forward one to another, you see all of them in your inbox.